# How the flex box converts from 3 column in to 2 column? what is the logic behind

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box > * {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
</div>
```

The above flex box converts from 3 column in to 2 column on shrink of the web page. what is the logic behind? when i set width as `33%` it should keep that percent right? how it's convert in to 2 column on page shrink? not able to understand.

[Live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ljkmyuHlZIFo08mT?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: The reason is the border is not accounted in the calculations. that 1px border will make it go above 33% probably.

Comment: add box-sizing: border-box

Comment: @mrafei /  Temani Afif yes you are right. but without the media query can't we make the 3 column in to 2 column or 1 column?

Comment: also 33% is not equal to 100/3. the correct value is 33.33%. Use the later and you will never get 3 columns